# App runs slow for the first few seconds?

Tags: iphone, ios, loading, frame-rate

I have made a game for iphone in which I am unsure how to 'load' the various components of the game. I have created a loading screen, which simply allows the game to run in the background for a few seconds. Normally, once the program has run for 10 or so seconds, it becomes much smoother and the frame rate speeds up dramatically. However, I have no idea as to why it runs slowly, and I was wondering if anybody could give me suggestions as to why this is, and how I might go about programmatically loading these things while the loading screen is showing. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Specifically, I am trying to load a number of `UIImageViews` and `UIVIews`, including a large background.

Comment: Not enough specifics. What are you loading at start-up, etc.

Comment: @skinnyTOD have edited my original post to specify what I am loading

Comment: Well, obviously that could be your problem. Do you need to load them all at start up? Can you do 'lazy loading' (load when needed)? Did you run Instruments to see how much memory is being allocated?

Comment: @skinnyTOD It could be the problem, however when I check whether they have been added as subviews of the main view in the app using `NSLog` statements, it says very quickly (in the first 2 or 3 seconds) that they have all been added as subviews, howver the game continues to move slowly. I have used instruments, and it appears not much memory is being allocated.

Comment: Well, process of elimination - can you disable loading some of them to see if it makes any difference? Same for any audio, etc. There is some feature in Instruments that (apparently) lets you see where time is spent - I haven't used it - might be worth checking out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I have discovered that the issue was simply that I was creating too many objects of a certain type, and that was dramatically slowing the framerate. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

The app need enough time to load UI components like imageview. That may be the reason behind your problem. One more thing to be noted is that, if you are doing too much things in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, the app will be rejected by apple. The app should be launched within 24 seconds. So, its better to show a loading screen and do your activities in background.

Comment: as stated in my reply to skinnyTOD, checking whether the `UIImageView`s have been added to the main view of the app by using `NSLog` statements seem to show that the `UIImageView`s are added in the first couple seconds. Do they still need to load in some way, even after they have been added as subviews to the main view?

Comment: Where do you put the code for loading the imageviews? In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Or other pages?